# React developer tools not showing in non create react app projects

Tags: reactjs

I am working in a react project which is not created by npx create-react-app. It was built by jhipster react app. I have installed react-devtools in my chrome, but devtools tab is not showing when other react websites showing

Comment: Please add links to the react app that you used to create.

Comment: https://github.com/jhipster/react-jhipster

Answer (score 0):

These steps may help since it's a common error with the new update.

1. Create a new profile in `Google Chrome`
2. Install the `React Developer Tools`
3. Go to https://reactjs.org
4. Open the browser `Dev Tools`. Sometimes when you can't see the tabs close `Dev Tools` and then switch to the other `page of SPA` (let it be `P2`). Open `Dev Tools` while on `P2`

Now you see `Components` and `Profiler` tabs

Without closing `Dev Tools`, switch back to `P1`, the two tabs of `RDT-extension` should still be there